# What Is The Error In This GCM Code

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am Trying to register the Device in the cloud (Google Cloud Messaging **GCM**)

but some Error facing the application

can you help me on this

Here's My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test09_gsm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <permission android:name="com.example.test09_gsm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test09_gsme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test09_gsm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                 <category android:name="com.example.test09_gsm" />
             </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Hers's The Class

```
package com.example.test09_gsm;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public static String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService(String senderId)
    {
        super(senderId);
        Log.d("GCMIntentService", senderId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onError", arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId){
        Log.d("onRecoverableError", errorId);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.d("onMessage", String.valueOf(arg1));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onRegistered", arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onUnregistered", arg1);
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
package com.example.test09_gsm;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals(""))
        {
          GCMRegistrar.register(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
        }
        else
        {
          Log.v("Info : ", "Already registered");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

LogCat

```
12-15 00:28:28.935: E/Trace(4569): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-15 00:28:29.085: D/GCMRegistrar(4569): resetting backoff for com.example.test09_gsm
12-15 00:28:29.085: V/GCMRegistrar(4569): Registering app com.example.test09_gsm of senders XXXXXXXXXXXX
12-15 00:28:29.160: D/libEGL(4569): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-15 00:28:29.165: D/libEGL(4569): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-15 00:28:29.165: D/libEGL(4569): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-15 00:28:29.170: D/(4569): Device driver API match
12-15 00:28:29.170: D/(4569): Device driver API version: 10
12-15 00:28:29.170: D/(4569): User space API version: 10 
12-15 00:28:29.170: D/(4569): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Wed Sep 12 17:53:53 KST 2012 
12-15 00:28:29.205: D/OpenGLRenderer(4569): Enabling debug mode 0
12-15 00:28:29.985: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(4569): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
12-15 00:28:29.985: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(4569): GCM IntentService class: com.example.test09_gsm.GCMIntentService
12-15 00:28:29.985: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4569): Acquiring wakelock
12-15 00:28:30.000: D/dalvikvm(4569): newInstance failed: no <init>()
12-15 00:28:30.000: D/AndroidRuntime(4569): Shutting down VM
12-15 00:28:30.000: W/dalvikvm(4569): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e372a0)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.test09_gsm.GCMIntentService: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.test09_gsm.GCMIntentService; no empty constructor
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2388)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.test09_gsm.GCMIntentService; no empty constructor
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2385)
12-15 00:28:30.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4569):     ... 10 more
```

now how can i resolve this problem and receive the registration ID And Use it

thanks in advance

Comment: We are not going to be able to produce a response for that wall of text.  Please give us the smallest possible program

Comment: Why not? The OP added relevant code and logcat. I looked at the bottom of the logcat and saw the error. Much better than someone posting a question with no code or error message in my opinion

Comment: @Woot4Moo

I want to do something like , I've small android application with almost 10 users this application related to sql server database

i need when some one of users add/update/delete something in database to push a notification of all other users and inform then (that some data changes in the database) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try after adding default constructor to  `GCMIntentService` as :

```
public GCMIntentService() {
        super("IntentService");
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much , how can i know what is the registration ID of the Device ?

Comment: @lo2i :most welcome . i don't known about that.

Comment: Do You know how can i push a notification through asp.net to rest of Devices?

Comment: @lo2i : friend i never use GCM i my application in current question i answer is according to service because `IntentService` always require a default constructor . i you have any other issue regrading gcm then ask them as new question here you will get good and quick answer here.thanks